# Dynamic increment of OIDs at SNMP Agent side

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

I am trying to implement a snmp agent with two different context name.I got some sample program from the http://snmplabs.com/ .
Following is how I am trying to implement my agent side. At the begining of the implementation I got some error like

```
Error: OID not increasing: SNMPv2-SMI::dod
 >= SNMPv2-SMI::dod
```

I got answer from the stackoverflow for that.

[Error: OID not increasing: SNMPv2-SMI::dod, How to increase OID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58977166/error-oid-not-increasing-snmpv2-smidod-how-to-increase-oid/58980756?noredirect=1#comment104583772_58980756)

So I fixed my code like

```py
class sample ():
    def readVars (self , varBinds, acInfo=(None, None)):
            retItem = []
            for ov in varBinds:
                if str(ov[0]) == '1.3.6.1.4.1.12345.1.1.1.0':
                    retItem.extend([(ov[0], v2c.OctetString('%s' % primary_keys['value1']))])
                elif str(ov[0]) == '1.3.6.1.4.1.12345.1.1.2.0':
                    retItem.extend([(ov[0], v2c.OctetString('%s' % primary_keys['value2']))])
                . 
                .
                .
                .

    def readNextVars (self , varBinds, acInfo=(None, None)):
            retItem = []
            for ov in varBinds:
                if str(ov[0]) == '1.3.6.1.4.1.12345.1.1.1.0':
                    retItem.extend([('1.3.6.1.4.1.12345.1.1.2.0', v2c.OctetString('%s' % primary_keys['value2']))])
                elif str(ov[0]) == '1.3.6.1.4.1.12345.1.1.2.0':
                    retItem.extend([('1.3.6.1.4.1.12345.1.1.3.1.1.0', v2c.OctetString('%s' % item_list['value3']]))])
                .
                .
                .
                .
            else:
                    retItem.extend([('1.3.6.1.4.1.44555.1.1.1.0', v2c.OctetString('%s' % primary_keys['value1']))])
            return retItem
```

and I registred this class under the context like this

```py
mibTreeA = sample()

self._snmpContext.registerContextName(v2c.OctetString('ContextOne'), mibTreeA)  
self._snmpContext.registerContextName(v2c.OctetString('ContextTwo'), mibTreeA)
```

But the problem is I want to use more than 50 OIDs in this, so I am thinking to make it dynamic, any suggestion or example for doing that. Please ask if you want more details.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably wrap your data into some suitable data structure and just look it up there by OID.

It even can be a no/SQL DB having (expanding on your code) RSA keys and their corresponding OIDs stored together...